# How Can I Get This PHP Script To Properly Display Newline?

Tags: php

My understanding of PHP is that you can use either "\n" or "\r\n" or `echo "<br>";` to create a new line. But my application of them simply doesn't create a new line.

What am I doing wrongly here?

Here is the code:

```html
<?php

session_start(); // before any HTML is echoed
 
if($_POST) {
    //$email = "";
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
     
    if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
        $email = str_replace(array("\r", "\n", "%0a", "%0d"), '', $_POST['email']);
        $email = filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);        
    }    
    if(isset($_POST['password'])) {
        $password = htmlspecialchars($_POST['password']);
    }
 
    $recipient = "myemail@domain.com";
     
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n"
    .'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n"
    .'From: ' . $email . "\r\n";
 
    $email_content .= "Email: $email" . "\r\n";
    echo "<br />\n";
    $email_content .= "Password: $password";
 
    echo $email_content;
     
    if(mail($recipient, $email_content, $headers)) {
       header("Location: default-image.png");
    echo "          <script language=javascript>
  //alert('Done, Click Ok');
  window.location='default-image.png';
  </script>";
    } else {
        echo '<p>ERROR! Please go back and try again.</p>';
    }
     
} else {
    echo '<p>Something went wrong</p>';
}
 
?>
```

Thanks for your time and input.

Comment: a newline in what context though? On the commandline `\n` or `PHP_EOL` but in HTML it should be `<br />`... Judging by the above you are trying to send in an email - unless it is HTML based the `BR` tag will not work. The `\r\n`  should be ok in a plain text based email afaik

Comment: You're showing two different attempts, which one specifically are you asking about?  The `echo` will go to the page output, but we don't know what (if anything) you ever do with `$email_content`.  Can you elaborate on the specific problem you're describing?

Answer (score 1):

You assign the values to a variable. The `echo` is not in that context and will output your values to your page output.

```
$email_content .= "Email: $email" . "\r\n";
$email_content .= "<br />\n";
$email_content .= "Password: $password";
echo $email_content;
```

That is the correct way.

The next thing is that `<br />` is the representation for a new line in HTML. `\n` and `\r\n` is the ASCII representation for a new line. This is mostly used in text files and other editors or CSV files for example. So you mixup different things.

Comment: Yes, I'm confused about the usage and seem to be mixing up things. I really don't want to print <br /> on the email message. Instead, I simply want the email message to look like this: "Email: value" on one line and "Password: value" will follow on the next line.

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr

Use \n to clean your code.  Use `<br />` to add break lines.  Make sure to concatenated `<br />` to your variable.

---

The \n will clean up the source code view and the `<br />` needs to be concatenated to your variable.

```
$email_content .= "Email: $email" . "<br />\n";
$email_content .= "Password: $password";
```

Note that if you don't include the \n, when viewing your source code in the browser, you might see that the html could be on the same line.

```
<?php

    $email = "foo";
    $password = "bar";
    $email_content1 = "";
    $email_content2 = "";

    //without the \n to cleanup the source code
    $email_content1 .= "Email: $email" . "<br />";
    $email_content1 .= "Password: $password";

    echo $email_content1;

    //ignore, used for break
    echo "\n\n<br />\n\n";

    //with the \n to cleanup the source code
    $email_content2 .= "Email: $email" . "<br />\n";
    $email_content2 .= "Password: $password";

    echo $email_content2;

?>
```

The source code would look like:

```
Email: foo<br />Password: bar

<br />

Email: foo<br />
Password: bar
```

Comment: Let me be clear; I want to create a newline right after "Email", so that the "Password" will be displayed below. What I want is simply the display the data like the following:
Email: value
Password: value

Comment: Check the last 4 lines of the code I posted above.  It will provide you what you are looking for and the XML/html source code should also be clean.  Use <br />\n at the end of your email line.

Answer (score 0):

You should use '\n' for new line it will show in output

```
$email_content .= "Email: $email" . "\n\n\n";
$email_content .= "\n\n";
$email_content .= "Password: $password";
echo $email_content;
```

you will see the password start with new line

Comment: Thanks for your time and input. But it simply didn't work for me.